# Mathematical modeling- oil spill?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling

An oil spill has fouled 200 miles of shoreline. The oil company responsible has been given 14 days to clean up the shoreline, after which a fine of  $$10/day$ will be imposed. The local clean up crew can scrub 5 miles of beach per week at a cost of $500/day. Additional crews can be brought in at a cost of $18 plus $800/day for each crew. 
How many additional crews should be brought in to minimize the total cost to the company?

I'm supposed to use these variables:

$n$= total number of crews, including the local crew

$n_0$=number of crews required to clean up the shoreline in exactly 14 days

$t$= number of days to clean up the oil spill

$c$= total cost (measured in thousands of dollars)

$t$=the amount of the fine (measure in thousands of dollars)

I'm stuck on this, I am having difficulty putting the pieces together. I'm supposed to find a formula for $t$ in terms of $n$, $t(n)$.

How can I relate the number of days to finish the job to the number of crews? How can I find the number of additional crews with my given variables?

I know that if $t>14$ or $n<n_0$, then they will have to pay a fine...

Comment: No oil company will move even one finger for a fine of $\$10$ a day.

Comment: @Did It's in thousands of dollars

Comment: Even in thousands of dollars.

Comment: @Did Lol, it does seem pretty harsh. That's the problem in my book though.

Comment: Then the authors have no idea about the sums involved. Or they do not care. Then why pretend describing real-life situations? (By the way, a 14 days delay is also ridiculous.)

Comment: What's a reasonable fine?

Comment: Basically, no fine is "reasonable" because the damage are irreversible. In practice, some data is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BP).

Comment: With these numbers, getting fined \$10 per day is still more convenient than hiring new people at a cost of \$800 per day! :-)